# Word VBA fails pasting into Footnotes

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, footnotes

I am trying to copy a piece of *formatted* text from one (rtf) document into a field in a Word document.
In Word2003, copy and paste via the clipboard works, but in Word2010, if the target range is in a footnote then the `Paste` operation fails (actually does nothing but does not give an error). In Word2010 however, using `PasteSpecial` works, but in Word365 that fails too.

This is my code:

```
If IsObjectValid(extIndex.getHeadingText(i)) Then
                        extIndex.getHeadingText(i).Copy
                        fieldCode.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
                        fieldCode.Paste
                    Else
```

Is there some other way to do this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You haven't told us whether there is a field in the footnote and you haven't shown use the code that determines what fieldCode refers to. Your code also appears to be pasting the content *after* the field, not *in* it.

Comment: Yes, there is a field, which has just been inserted by code previously. It is an XE field and the Collapse is as per the Range.Paste description in the Word VBA reference manual to insert at the end of the field rather than in the middle. The code works completely successfully when run under Word2003, and in all versions when the field is in the main text of the document.